# All checkboxes returned checked, even if " "

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of records which I use a repeater to display on screen.  One of the columns contains a checkbox 'Contacted'.  I have set some of the records to be checked and some not.( In the DB)...but when the page loads all the records are checked...Does anyone know why?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkBox"
 checked='<%# SetCheckboxValue((bool)Eval("Contacted"))%>' />
```

"Contacted" is a bool set in the code behind depending if the record is checked or not(from the DB)

```
protected string SetCheckboxValue(bool Contacted)
    {
        if (Contacted)
        {
            return "checked";
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }
```

SetCheckboxValue gets either T or F and should return "checked" or " "
Then the application should display each record as checked or empty..but as I said all of the records are appearing as checked?

Any idea guys?
Thanks

Comment: `Contacted` what is the value? is it true or "T" ?

Comment: hi ravi it is a bool, so it is true

Comment: Is that usage of `Eval` legal?  I don't see it in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.eval.aspx), but I don't use it myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the attribute `checked` is a boolean attribute and doesn't necessarily require a value.

It's presence or absence indicates whether the check-box is checked or not.

Change your mark-up to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" <%# SetCheckboxValue((bool)Eval("Contacted"))%> />
```

Note: That in order to be X/HTML compliant you should generate the attribute mark-up as: `checked="checked"` but for HTML the simpler `checked` is enough.

```
protected string SetCheckboxValue(bool Contacted)
{
    if (Contacted)
    {
        return "checked=\"checked\"";
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`checked` in the value is not necessary and completely optional.

```
<input type='checkbox' checked />
```

is same as

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' />
```

is same as

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='' />
```

You need to remove the attribute `checked` completely to un-check the checkbox.